# Python computation Error

Tags: python, output

I found something really strange happening in python with that code:

```
num = 99999999999999999999999999999

for i in range(2, num):
    if num % i == 0:
        j = int(num / i)
        print(num, '=', i, '*', j)
        break
else:
    print(num, 'is prime')
```

Python is giving me

```
99999999999999999999999999999 = 3 * 33333333333333333409747959808
```

as output, what is obviouly wrong. And as bigger `num` is getting, the wronger the output gets.

Can someone tell me, what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect you're using Python 3.  In Python 3, when dividing integers with the `/` operator, it converts them to float and produces a float result.  Floats have limited precision, so you're seeing roundoff errors.

To get integer division, without roundoff errors, you can use the `//` operator, which gives true integer division.  Just change the assignment to `j` to:

```
j = num // i
```